# Replace/delete special characters within matched strings in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file containing lines like

```
I want a lot <*tag 1> more <*tag 2>*cheese *cakes.
```

I am trying to remove the * within `<>` but not outside. The tags can be more complicated than above. For example, `<*better *tag 1>`.

I tried `/\bregex\b/s/\*//g`, which works for tag 1 but not tag 2. So how can I make it work for tag 2 as well?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you have nested `<>`?

Comment: In my case, there'll be no nested <>. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obligatory Perl solution:

```
perl -pe '$_ = join "",
        map +($i++ % 2 == 0 ? $_ : s/\*//gr),
        split /(<[^>]+>)/, $_;' FILE
```

**Append:**

```
perl -pe 's/(<[^>]+>)/$1 =~ s(\*)()gr/ge' FILE
```

Comment: Great perl one-liner. +1 from me too.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution if you have only one asterisk in tag

```
sed 's/<\([^>]*\)\*\([^>]*\)>/<\1\2>/g'
```

If you can have more, you can use sed goto label system

```
sed ':doagain s/<\([^>]*\)\*\([^>]*\)>/<\1\2>/g; t doagain'
```

Where *doagain* is label for loop, *t doagain* is conditional jump to label doagain. Refer to the sed manual:

```
t label

 Branch to label only if there has been a successful substitution since the last 
 input line was read or conditional branch was taken. The label may be omitted, in 
 which case the next cycle is started.
```

Comment: Thanks for the loop solution. :-)

Comment: You asked for sed solution :) I'm glad it helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

**awk** could solve your problem:

```
awk '{x=split($0,a,/<[^>]*>/,s);for(i in s)gsub(/\*/,"",s[i]);for(j=1;j<=x;j++)r=r a[j] s[j]; print r}' file
```

more readable version:

```
 awk '{x=split($0,a,/<[^>]*>/,s)
       for(i in s)gsub(/\*/,"",s[i])
       for(j=1;j<=x;j++)r=r a[j] s[j]
       print r}' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat file
I want a lot <*tag 1> more <*tag 2>*cheese *cakes. <*better *tag X*>

kent$  awk '{x=split($0,a,/<[^>]*>/,s);for(i in s)gsub(/\*/,"",s[i]);for(j=1;j<=x;j++)r=r a[j] s[j]; print r}' file
I want a lot <tag 1> more <tag 2>*cheese *cakes. <better tag X>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 4-argument version of `split`, what is the fourth argument?